# Не работает должным образом

Tags: android, android-studio

В теории этот таймер не дает запуститься приложению, пока нет интернета.

```
@Override
    public void onPause()  {
        super.onPause();  
        int i=1,g=5;
        while(i<2){

        if(isOnline()){
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            break;
        }else{
            while(i<2){
            while(g>0){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();}
                TextView timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
                timer.setText("Нет подключения к интернету\nПовторная попытка через:");
                g--;}
                g=5;}
        }
    }
}

@Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }
```

Comment: `не дает запуститься приложению, пока нет интернета` – это чтобы нельзя было пользоваться без рекламы? )

Comment: Конечно он не работает. Вы используете findViewById, при том что не вызвали setContentView. Код внутри catch будет падать в ошибку. Вообще не хорошо так делать. Система подумает что ваше приложение зависло выкинет ANR или вовсе убъет процесс

Comment: В чём заключается вопрос?